# Can I get Android PackageInstaller Install cancel button callback?

Tags: java, android, packageinstaller

[image]
I using `PackageInstaller` API to install my apk. 
Can I get Android `PackageInstaller` cancel button callback ?
if yes , How can I do? Or it just impossible.

Comment: Did you get the answers? I am also searching for the same.

Comment: @SaurabhPadwekar it is long time ago , I forgot.

Answer (score -2):

If you know you are going to install, you will know whether it is installed successfully.

Comment: OP means how to know it programmatically.